# En este simulador de compras Javascript no puedo encontrar el error al querer agregar items al el carrito pues arroja undefined

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles, function, undefined

Tengo este código pero al intentar agregar items al carrito mediante la función agregarCarrito arroja este error al entrar al primera case del switch: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nombre') line 78".
No se si estaré accesando mal a las propiedades del objeto en el array o tengo algún otro error que no logro observar y me da como consecuencia este...

```
class Producto {
    constructor(id, nombre, descripcion, precio, stock, img) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre.toUpperCase();
        this.descripcion = descripcion.toUpperCase();
        this.precio = precio;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.img = img;
    }

    sinIva() {
        this.precio = this.precio - this.precio * 0.21;
    }

    actualizarStock(x) {
        this.stock = this.stock - x;
    }
}

// Creamos un arrary de productos
const productos = [
new Producto(1, "estilo1", "tripico de dise;o de modas.", 5400, 6, "./images/cuadros/1.jpg"),
new Producto(2, "estilo2", "tripico de dise;o de modas.", 5400, 6, "./images/cuadros/2.jpg"),
new Producto(3, "estilo3", "tripico de dise;o de modas.", 5400, 6, "./images/cuadros/3.jpg"),
new Producto(4, "mapa1", "tripico de mapas de ciudades.", 5400, 6, "./images/cuadros/4.jpg"),
new Producto(5, "mapa2", "tripico de mapas de ciudades.", 5400, 6, "./images/cuadros/5.jpg"),
new Producto(6, "mapa3", "tripico de mapas de ciudades.", 6400, 6, "./images/cuadros/6.jpg"),
new Producto(7, "arte", "cuadro de arte.", 3200, 6, "./images/cuadros/7.jpg"),
new Producto(8, "arte1", "cuadro de arte.", 3200, 6, "./images/cuadros/8.jpg")
];




// Insertamos productos por DOM

const destino = document.getElementById("principal");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


    for (let i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("col-md-3");
        div.id = "contenedorImagen";
        div.innerHTML = `
                <div class="cuadro-boton">
                    <img src="${productos[i].img}" class="imagenCuadros"> </img>
                    <div class="container">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${productos[i].nombre}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">${productos[i].descripcion}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">$${productos[i].precio}</p>
                        <button id="botonCarrito" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="${productos[i].id}">Comprar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
        fragment.appendChild(div)
    }
    

destino.appendChild(fragment);




// Creamos un arrary de productos
let total = 0;

function agregarCarrito() {
    let otros;

    do {
        let producto = prompt("Queres comprar cuadros?");
        let cantidad = parseInt(prompt("Cuantos queres comprar?"));
        let precio;

        switch (producto) {
            case Producto[0].nombre:
                Producto[0].actualizarStock(cantidad);
                if (Producto[0].stock < 0 || isNaN(cantidad)) {
                    alert("Lo sentimos, en este momento no tenemos stock")
                    Producto[0].stock = Producto[0].stock + cantidad;
                    precio = 0;
                    cantidad = 0;
                } else {
                    precio = Producto[0].precio;
                }
                break;

            case Producto[1].nombre:
                Producto[1].actualizarStock(cantidad);
                if (Producto[1].stock < 0 || isNaN(cantidad)) {
                    alert("Lo sentimos, en este momento no tenemos stock")
                    Producto[1].stock = Producto[1].stock + cantidad;
                    precio = 0;
                    cantidad = 0;
                } else {
                    precio = Producto[1].precio;
                }
                break;

            default:
                alert("Alguno de los ingresados no es correcto");
                precio = 0;
                cantidad = 0;
                break;
        }
        total = total + precio + cantidad;
        otros = confirm("Queres agregar otro cuadro?");
    }
    while (otros);

}


function comprar() {
    agregarCarrito();
}

 let carrito = document.getElementById('botonCarrito');
 carrito.addEventListener("click", comprar);
```

Answer (score 2):

En el switch estas referenciando la clase Producto, no el array productos que contiene los productos creados.

```
 switch (producto) {
            case Producto[0].nombre:
                Producto[0].actualizarStock(cantidad);
                if (Producto[0].stock < 0 || isNaN(cantidad)) {
                    alert("Lo sentimos, en este momento no tenemos stock")
                    Producto[0].stock = Producto[0].stock + cantidad;
                    precio = 0;
                    cantidad = 0;
                } else {
                    precio = Producto[0].precio;
                }
                break;

-----

 switch (producto) {
            case productos[0].nombre:
                productos[0].actualizarStock(cantidad);
                if (productos[0].stock < 0 || isNaN(cantidad)) {
                    alert("Lo sentimos, en este momento no tenemos stock")
                    productos[0].stock = productos[0].stock + cantidad;
                    precio = 0;
                    cantidad = 0;
                } else {
                    precio = productos[0].precio;
                }
                break;
```